# How to display the full name string of files and folders in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7 64bit, and I cannot find a way to show the full name string of files and folders when I am in "View > Small Icons or Medium Icons".

On Vista, for example, when you clicked once on a file or folder with a long name, the full name was expanded and was displayed. Now, with Win 7 64bit, it is only displayed if you try to rename the file or folder.

[image]

[Here is a small video](http://tinypic.com/r/fm89x/5), too

1. I want to keep small or medium icon size View. Not large or very
   large.
2. I want to keep Icon View, and not change it to detail View

Comment: If you click on the path ("test" in your screenshot), the full path should appear.  I haven't been able to find a way to get this to be the default either.  Good question (+1).

Comment: @RandolfRichardson Perhaps Check out [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/features.html), it has a tweak to put the full path in the Explorer title bar. I've never used it personally. :)

Answer (score 3):

Some of these people are answering questions that you are not asking. I think they believe you have a problem finding the full path of your files/folder.
Anyway, I think I may have a solution for you. If you right click the desktop-> personalize, then click "window color", then "click advanced appearance settings.."; from there you can try and mess around with the icon size, icon spacing vertical/horizontal, plus a few other ones. I had a problem with the way my icons were being displayed and this was the only area I found in Windows 7 64 bit where you could change/edit icon settings.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that's just not the way it works in Windows 7 anymore, and there doesn't seem to be an in-built way to adjust the Explorer row heights (or alike) for these icon sizes.

If you hover over a file with the mouse, the tooltip will tell you the full file name:

[image]

Here's the rules to how the text is displayed ([according to a Microsoft TechNet moderator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/14a56091-892c-4d3a-8fe1-08392367c66d/)):

- For "Extra Large Icons", "Large Icons", and "Medium Icons", the file name display length is depended on the icon size.
- For "Small Icons" and "Titles", the file name display length is fixed.
- For "Content", the file name display length is depended on the width of the Windows Explorer window.
- For "List", the file name display length is fixed and also is depended on the width of the Windows Explorer window.
- For "Details", the file name display length can be changed by dragging the column border. In this view, you can try "Size Column to Fit".

Comment: Thank you techie007! Its a pity that Microsoft will not give this option anymore. I cannot understand the "logic" behind this decision, though...  (I cannot vote for your answer since I am only a guest, so +1 for your fast reply!)

Answer (score 0):

you can find out the full path by right clinking the folder from the tool bar at the top (eg test as in the example above) and selct 'copy address as text' and then put it in your search bar which will give you the full UNC path

Answer (score -2):

This post is REALLY old, but I found a way to do it in Windows 10. I'm unsure if it works in Windows 7.

I successfully was able to make the name display longer by dragging the *Name* column. Here's a screenshot as an example.

[image: Example]

The circled line is draggable, and can be resized. I just dragged mine all the way to the end to get the maximum amount of space.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question because the OP specified *I want to keep small or medium icon size View*. Your answer requires use of the Detailed view.